# How to create an overlay over a view

Tags: html, css

I am trying to set an overlay in my web page but I am unable to do this. My code for setting an overlay over a view is like this:

```css
#cover {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: #000;
    z-index: 1;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: none;
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<div id="cover">
    <p>-----</p>
</div>
```

But I'm not getting the desired output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just remove the `display: none`, you should be able to view the overlay

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <style type="text/css">
    #cover {
      position: fixed;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      background: #000;
      z-index: 1;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      opacity: 0.5;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="cover">
    <p>-----</p>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks , i got it.